# Grab scrollbar below and above scrollbar track functionality?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, scrollbar

So I've been given an untrivial task to make a thin scrollbar, that can be grabbed above and below as I showed in the picture.
[image]

I figured out how to make it one way - I made scrollbar very high - 32px, gave it a transparent background and mimiced scrollbar tracker and thumb with very thin inset box-shadow, but as I pointed out on picture 2, I can only grab it below, but not above (naturally).
[image]

These pictures are wrapped in this div:

```
        width: 218px;
        height: 165px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        display: flex;
        padding-top: 18px;
        padding-left: 3px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        flex-direction: row;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        gap: 10px;
        position: static;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;

        cursor: pointer;

        @-moz-document url-prefix() {
            & {
                scrollbar-width: thin;
                scrollbar-color: #0090ff #aeafbc;
            }
        }

        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 2px;
            height: 32px;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 0 #aeafbc;
            background: transparent;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            width: 66px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 0 #0090ff;
            background: transparent;
        }
}
```

Please, if you know some workaround, I'd be very grateful!